# Как получить ссылку от пользователя? Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Python, Selenium.
Как функцию input сохранить в переменную и попросить пользователя ввести туда ссылку. Далее через Selenium открыть её используя эту переменную. Пример моего кода, который не работает:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "C:\Riot Games\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

link = input("Введите ссылку на объявление Youla: ")
driver.get(link)
```

Comment: А что вводится в `link`?

Comment: В моей фантазии link это переменная которая сохраняет введенные данные пользователем (в данном случае ссылка). driver.get(link) должен открывать в браузере эту ссылку

Comment: ну, так и введите туда ссылку, по коду она должна открыться selenium'ом :)

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы открывалась ссылка которую ввел именно пользователь

Comment: Запускаете код, после `Введите ссылку на объявление Youla: ` вводите, например, `https://ya.ru` и в окне браузера селениума будет открыт этот сайт. Если я неправильно вас понял, то опиши подробнее

Comment: Я пытаюсь использовать это. Я не могу сделать так, чтобы функция driver.get(link) открывала введенную пользователем ссылку. Проще говоря я не могу понять как написать функцию driver.get и поместить туда переменную (чтобы driver.get(link) открывал введенную пользователем ссылку в переменную link. driver.get(link) у меня не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def request_url():
    link = input("Введите ссылку на объявление Youla: ")
    browser(link)


def browser(link):
    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('https://' + link)


request_url()
```